# How to find the instance before a peak forms in a signal?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I am working with signal data and am trying to find the instance (or close to it) before a peak starts to form. For example:

[image: Peak examples]

The red stars and orange x's are currently calculated using scipy.signal.find_peaks to find the first minimum peak before two peaks greater than 50 in a row. The ideal location I want is the area with the red stars and the second and third orange x.

My problem is that sometimes there is not a minimum value right before that first hump forms and that causes a problem like with the first orange x on the left.

What would be a better method or a way to improve my current method to get that spot right before the hump forms (rough arrow location):

[image]

My current code looks something like this, and it runs for the blue and green lines separately:

```
    step_peak, _ = find_peaks(z, height=60, distance=40)
    step_min, _ = find_peaks(-1*z, height=-60)
    contact = []

    for i in range(len(step_peak)-1):
        if step_peak[i+1] - step_peak[i] < 100:
            for min in reversed(step_min):
                if min < step_peak[i]:
                    contact.append(min)
                    break
```

This method works for about 90% of the entire dataset, there are only a few that end up like the first orange x that I need to account for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the point you're looking for is where the second derivative is largest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's look at the function `scipy.signal.peak_widths`. Without access to your data, I used a sample curve:

```py
from scipy.signal import chirp, find_peaks, peak_widths
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 6 * np.pi, 1000)
x = np.sin(x) + 0.6 * np.sin(2.6 * x)

peaks, _ = find_peaks(x)
results_full = peak_widths(x, peaks, rel_height=1)
results_full[0]  # widths
plt.plot(x)
plt.plot(peaks, x[peaks], "x")
plt.hlines(*results_full[1:], color="C3")
plt.show()
```

[image]

We can parse the results of `peak_widths`  to discard those values that are inside of another widths.

```py
peak_begin = np.array(results_full)
peak_begin = peak_begin[:, np.argsort( peak_begin[2] ) ] 
_, b = peak_begin.shape
width_to_delete = []
i= 1
while i < b:
    if peak_begin[2][i] < peak_begin[3][i-1]:
        peak_begin = np.delete(peak_begin,i,1)
        b = b-1
    else:
        i = i+1

plt.plot(x)
plt.hlines(*results_full[1:], color="r")
plt.plot(peaks, x[peaks], "x")
plt.plot(peak_begin[2], peak_begin[1], "o", color="g")
plt.show()
```

[image]

I hope that I got what you want to achieve.